# Writing Emacs Packages in Java

Tags: package, java

I am an okay Java programmer and have very little knowledge of Emacs lisp, but I would still like to be able to write some packages for Emacs.
Is there a way or package that would allow me to write a package in Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't directly write an Emacs package in Java.  There is currently no way to extend Emacs in Java, nor is there a Java to Elisp transpiler.

It's common, though, to have Emacs run other programs to do work for it.  You could write a helper program like this in Java.  Whether this makes sense depends on what exactly you intend to do.

Comment: What I meant is if there was a package that would run Java programs.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a little snippet that allows to run a single Java file:

```
(defun java-eval-nofocus ()
  "Run current Java file."
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (let* ((source (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
         (out (file-name-sans-extension source))
         (class (concat out ".class")))
    (setenv "CLASSPATH" default-directory)
    (shell-command (format "rm -f %s && javac %s" class source))
    (if (file-exists-p class)
        (message (shell-command-to-string (format "java %s" out)))
      (progn
        (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
             (format "javac %s" source))
        (command-execute 'compile)))))
```

You can simplify it for your purposes, for instance, assume you have
`Utility.class` on your CLASSPATH, that prints some useful info like
today's weather. Then to insert this info into a buffer you need:

```
(defun insert-weather ()
  (interactive)
  (insert
   (shell-command-to-string "java Utility")))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-w") 'insert-weather)
```

Still, you won't be able to do anything more useful than inserting
static text unless you learn some Elisp.